# Editing existing user profiles ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add the feature of editing existing user profiles, I am not using Identity fyi.

However I am doing something wrong.

I have a single model as below

```
public partial class Users
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //email
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Your Email..")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //username
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Username..")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    //password
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Password...")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    //confirm
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm...")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPass { get; set; }
}
```

And I also have two separate controllers, one that handles user registration and the other handles user login. I have the Edit profile in the controller that contains the registration, as follows

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly TAContext _context;

    public UsersController(TAContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([Bind("Id,Name,Email,Username,Password,ConfirmPass")] Users uc) //register users
    {
        _context.Add(uc);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        //return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Users");
        return View(uc); //uc?
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
    {
        var ucc = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

        return View(ucc);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid id, [Bind("Id,Name,Email,Username,Password,ConfirmPass")] Users uc) //register users
    {
        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
        //    _context.Entry(uc).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}

        //_context.Update(uc);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 
        //return View(uc);
        if (id != uc.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(uc);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(uc.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Logusers");
        }

        return View(uc);
    }

    private bool UserExists(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Users.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Here is the view for editing:

```
@model TA.Models.Users

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
<div class=" container2">
    <hr />
    <h1>User edit</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ConfirmPass" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ConfirmPass" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPass" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save User Details" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger">@ViewBag.message</span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="return-to-hp">Back to Homepage</a>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Update me if you want to check the controller that has the login part.

I tried copying the scaffolding, but nothing worked.

Edit 1:
Invalid validation state for Id
[image: Invalid validation state for Id]

Comment: You should not be using Entity types (`class Users`) as two-way ViewModels in ASP.NET Core. You need to define a separate form-view-model class.

Comment: _"However I am doing something wrong."_ - okay, but you haven't told us what the problem actually is...

Comment: @Dai I believe the parameter of Edit method is not passing the Guid of the user logged in, it is null. I am not sure if that is the whole case.

Comment: @Dai, so I should create a new model, then go to my controller and add the view needed while making sure the view is using the data from the new model? Why should that be the case?

Comment: Why is the `Edit(Guid? id)` parameter nullable?

Comment: `<form asp-action="Edit">` <-- what is the **rendered** HTML for this element? You don't seem to be using explicit routes, so you're using implicit/"convention-based" routing, which will make it harder to troubleshoot request routing issues.

Comment: I changed it into Edit(Guid id), but it is now passing {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Comment: I can not understand your second question. I know that this references the Edit action.

Comment: What is the problem by the way? Do you get an exception? At what point does it not work?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions, I just want to find a way to make that Id from the User Model is passed into the Edit parameters (if that's the correct way to do it). By the way, when I remove <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" /> from the view, everything starts to be treated like creating data i.e. user registration and not profile editing, it defeats the purpose of updating the database contents.

Comment: So your binding is failing? I'd start with a really basic example project to get familiar with binding. By default you don't have to specify anything like the "[Bind("Id,Name,Email,Username,Password,ConfirmPass")]". If it's just a basic class with properties, the binding will happen automatically. Also I just use @Html.EditorFor(m => m) to create the Html as a first shot. If it works I might make some more fancy handmate html later.

Comment: Maybe binding is the issue, I will work on this tomorrow and I will update you.

Comment: Alright, I am back.. The removal of the binding does not resolve the issue, however, I am sure that the problem is when lets say I register and login a user, the Guid of the user is not saved for the next steps of the app's features like when I want to edit the profile, the ModelState of the Guid Id is invalid.