# Authorization not working fully right ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I have this project which has login, logout and signup. The privacy page is included there for logged-in users to access only. Here are 4 scenarios I used to test out the authorization of users.

1- I click the privacy page, I can access it even without logging in. [Negative result]

2- I login and logout then try to enter the privacy page, I can't access it. [Positive result]

3- I login and logout then close the website, and run the program again. Then try to access the privacy page, I can't access it. [Positive result]

4- I login then close the website, then run the program again, try to access the privacy page (it shows that I am signed out) and I can access it. [Negative result].

Refer to my other question for relevant code snippets (make sure to check the updated Startup.cs file at the bottom) [Authorization is not working properly in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76937183/authorization-is-not-working-properly-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

In cookie authentication, when you login using `SignInAsync`, it will generate a cookie in the your website domain which stored in the browser. As long as you have this cookie, you are in the status of signed in .  You could see this cookie in browser F12.(The tag maybe different depending on the browser.)

[image]

When you do `SignOutAsync`, you will delete this cookie. Now you requirement is  basically delete this cookie when close the browser. Just set `IsPersistant=False` in authProperties will let the cookie being deleted when session ends (browser closed).

```
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {             
                    IsPersistent = false,
                };
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-an-authentication-cookie-1

Comment: Unfortunately "IsPersistent = false," did not resolve the issue

Comment: @TutorialHellVeteran, please visit the URL from another browser after the app start with a defaut browser. My vs default browser is edge, it doesn't clear cookie. But if you use another brower it will work.

Comment: Well, I did as you said and it worked, but when I did the whole process again, it didn't work anymore. Is this normal? Will this take place if let's say the web app was actually deployed?

Comment: @TutorialHellVeteran I tested with depoly to IIS. All browsers work well to delete cookie after close and reopen browser. But will not work if you keeps the browser open just close a tab.